# binding data to a nonnative html property within Angular

Tags: angular, data-binding

I like to bind some data from database to an unnatural tag element in an Angular app, this is related to "Isotope filter":
I want to change this

```js
<li><a href="#" data-filter=".joomla"></li>
```

to

```js
<li *ngFor="let cat of categories;index as i">
<a href="#" class="active" [data-filter]=categoriesId[i]>{{cat.Title}}</a>
```

where categoriesId is an array of string in my ts file, but I face this error :

*Can't bind to 'data-filter' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.*

am I doing an impossible action? if yes is there any solution to do something like that?

Comment: try `[attr.data-filter]="categoriesId[i]"`

Comment: wow! thank you, it's worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Attribute binding syntax which is documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-types-and-targets):

```html
<li *ngFor="let cat of categories;index as i">
    <a href="#" class="active" [attr.data-filter]=categoriesId[i]>{{cat.Title}}</a>
</li>
```